# Java JOOQ with SQL Server: Caching queries

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jooq

I am using JOOQ with Microsoft SQL Server 2019. It states in this reference,

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/performance-considerations/

> It takes some time to construct jOOQ queries. If you can reuse the
> same queries, you might cache them.

Does JOOQ remove any of Microsoft SQL server caching abilities? Is there anything I should do specifically with JOOQ to cache sql plans, or will SQL server automatically take care of it?

[SQL Server caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Does jooq has any performance lead over simple sql in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861719/does-jooq-has-any-performance-lead-over-simple-sql-in-java)

Comment: _Does JOOQ remove any of Microsoft SQL server caching abilities?_ Sort of. SQL Server caches execution plans keyed on the `@@OPTIONS` in combination with the statement hash. This works well for reused statements and parameterised queries. Amongst other things jOOQ supports statements with [inlined parameters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/) which actually inject the query parameter values into the SQL statement - that means the statements are different and so will have different execution plans when used with different parameters.

Comment: @LukasEder I never said it does it by default. But if you use inlined parameters you defeat SQL Server's plan caching by submitting a different plan for each combination of parameters.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: But the OP's question is a general question, your point is about a specific feature that has nothing to do with jOOQ in general. You can inline values with any approach of sending statements to SQL Server, including using JDBC directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It takes some time to construct jOOQ queries. If you can reuse the same queries, you might cache them.

This is about the client side generation of the *SQL string*, which is re-generated every time you run a SQL query ([with jOOQ's queries being all dynamic by default](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/)). The same page that you quoted above also says:

> Optimise wisely

In rare cases, jOOQ's *client side* overhead may be a problem for your application's throughput. In those cases, you might be interested in caching the SQL string or even the prepared statement in the client, but you should do so only when you can *measure* an actual problem.

> Does JOOQ remove any of Microsoft SQL server caching abilities?

No, not at all. All jOOQ queries are created as [JDBC `PreparedStatement` using bind values by default](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/statement-type/). You can obviously override this default because there are always reasons to do so, but the default is to use prepared statements to benefit prepared statement caching on the server side.

> Is there anything I should do specifically with JOOQ to cache sql plans, or will SQL server automatically take care of it?

SQL server will automatically take care of it.

Comment: @mattsmith5: You can do that manually. But you shouldn't worry about it unless you are very sure this is a bottleneck.

Comment: @mattsmith5: Well, you asked that in your other question, so I answered there :)

Comment: by the way, I assume JOOQ works with AzureSQL and other mssql cloud based services, probably Amazon AWS with Sqlserver vm? I assume it would, as all it does creates JDBC statements underneath, our company is thinking of cloud migration, thanks again and amazing product !

Comment: @mattsmith5: Yes it works on AzureSQL. There are the usual limitations, because it doesn't work exactly the same way as a local SQL Server installation (e.g. things like this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12291), but we'll keep an eye out for such issues and fix accordingly, if needed.